# How to keep the data after removing the datasouce from a datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am populating a DataGridView (grid1) either by DataTable or DataSet.
I can remove a set of selected rows then add them to another unbound DataGridView (grid2).
The problem arises when I take a row from grid2 then add it to grid1.

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows
>   collection when the control is data-bound.

This occurs because

```
grid1.DataSource = myDataTable
or
grid1.DataSource = myDataSet
```

but when I do

```
grid1.DataSource = Nothing
```

all the rows from grid1 is removed.

Is there anyway to detach a datagridview from its datasource but keep the rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a solution wherein I would add another unbound DataGridView (grid3),
copy the content of the bound datagridview (grid1) to grid3 programmatically
then manipulate it from there.

Comment: It is working now. Though this is just a work around, if someone knows how to solve this either than this one. Please do so, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but have a look at the Copy method:

```
grid1.DataSource = myDataTable.Copy
```

The MSDN says *"Copies both the structure and data for this DataTable."*
It may be that copying it also un-binds it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a databound grid, you should probably not be playing with the rows in the grid at all. Alter the table that you set as the datasource, then the grid will reflect the new rows.

```
dim row as datarow = myDataTable.newrow()
row.item("Column1") = "new value"
myDataTable.rows.add(row)
```

now the new row will show up on the databound grid. You can remove rows from the grid by removing it from the datasource datatable as well.